# Laravel -The process has been signaled with signal "11"

Tags: php, unix, laravel-5, server

I am using laravel 5.4  version.
When Update the composer, I got below error.

**php artisan optimizeonen [Symfony\Compt\Process\Exception\RuntimeException] The process has been signaled with signal "11"**.
[image]
Then i am using artisan comment i got below error

**Segmentation fault**

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20988